# Multiple threads with notifyAll()

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a java program that print seconds elapsed, and every 5th second it will print a message. This is a sample output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 hello 5 6 7 8 9 hello 10 11 12 13 14 hello 15 16 17 18 19 hello
```

How can I remove the boolean variable printMsg? Is there a better thread design that allow this?

For now, without printMsg the program will print multiple "hello" during the 1/10 second program staying at 5, 10, 15 etc.

```
class Timer {
    private int count = 0;
    private int N;
    private String msg;
    private boolean printMsg = false;

    public Timer(String s, int N) {
        msg = s;
        this.N = N;
    }

    public synchronized void printMsg() throws InterruptedException{
        while (count % N != 0 || !printMsg)
            wait();
        System.out.print(msg + " ");
        printMsg = false;
    }

    public synchronized void printTime() {
        printMsg = true;
        System.out.print(count + " ");
        count ++;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer t = new Timer("hello", 5);
        new TimerThread(t).start();
        new MsgThread(t).start();
    }
}

class TimerThread extends Thread {
    private Timer t;
    public TimerThread(Timer s) {t = s;}

    public void run() {
        try {
            for(;;) {
                t.printTime();
                sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}

class MsgThread extends Thread {
    private Timer t;
    public MsgThread(Timer s) {t = s;}

    public void run() {
        try {
            for(;;) {
                t.printMsg();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the `count % N != 0` check in `printTime` and only call `notifyAll` when it's `true`

Comment: Shouldn't it be sleeping 1000 ms rather than 100 ms. Because you want to print message every 5 secs  `sleep(1000)`; instead of  `sleep(100)`; With this code it is printing message every 500 ms..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to use printMsg flag, just `notifyAll` when `count % N == 0`

```
public synchronized void printMsg() throws InterruptedException {
    wait();
    System.out.print(msg + " ");        
}

public synchronized void printTime() {      
    System.out.print(count + " ");
    count++;
    if (count % N == 0){
        notifyAll();    
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option to simplify and better design is to use single thread instead of two threads. And let the single thread take care of printing seconds as well as message. That way reduce one thread and don't need to wait() and notify. Is there is any reason why you want to use two threads? Code below:

```
public class Timer {
    private int count = 0;
    private int N;
    private String msg;

    public Timer(String s, int N) {
        msg = s;
        this.N = N;
    }

    public synchronized void printTime() {
        System.out.print(count + " ");
        count ++;
        if(count % N == 0) {
            System.out.print(msg + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer t = new Timer("hello", 5);
        new TimerThread(t).start();
    }
}

class TimerThread extends Thread {
    private Timer t;
    public TimerThread(Timer s) {t = s;}

    public void run() {
        try {
            for(;;) {
                t.printTime();
                sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```